# httpRequest.getCookies() is not fetching all cookies

Tags: java, spring-mvc, session, cookies

I am fetching cookies with the following code:

```
Cookie[] cookies = httpRequest.getCookies();
```

Sometimes it fetches all the cookies, sometimes it doesn't.

[image: screenshot 1]

As shown in the image, in inspect element its showing 2 SESSION cookies.

But as shown in the second image it's only fetching one. Why is this happening?

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Both are same cookies. Check the value

Comment: actually one cookie is browser created ans the other is which my code created with integer.maxvalue age... some times its showing as 2 cookies but sometimes its fetching only one.

Comment: Check the `domain` and `path` values for the cookies. The fact that they appear the same doesn't mean the are the same or valid for the URL you are calling.

Comment: i have not set both domain path, they are null.